# FingerPrint mismatch error when updating application on google play

Tags: android

i am developing an application. i developed the first version with titanium appcelerator and installed it on google play. but i developed its second version with Eclipse.
now when i am trying to upload it on google play it is giving the error of fingerprint mismatch means certificates of first version is not matching with the certificates of second verison. Can anyone tell me what certificates titanium appcelerator use and changes i need to do in seconde version so that i can upload it on the market.

thanks